# Text over an ellipse in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, text, ellipse

I am looking to have text displayed in an ellipse.  The code I have currently is:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource ThresholdBtnTemp}" Background="Green">
     <TextBlock Text="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="3" Template="{StaticResource ThresholdBtnTemp}" Background="Yellow" />
<Button Grid.Column="4" Template="{StaticResource ThresholdBtnTemp}" Background="Red" Content="2" />
```

and

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ThresholdBtnTemp" TargetType="Button" >
    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Black" Margin="2" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Neither the Red nor the Green will show the values as I have requested.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your controltemplate to "present" its content.  Try changing your ControlTemplate to:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ThresholdBtnTemp" TargetType="Button" >
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Black" Margin="2" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```